# Compress away all parents in a repository?

Tags: mercurial

I removed my last question because I think I'll ask a more simple question: Is there a way to compress ALL parents of a node (Basically, "pretend the repository starts here").

So turn

```
 o---o----o---o----o ....... x--+--+----+--+----+
     \    \        /                 \         /
      o---o---o----o                  *----*---*
```

into

```
 x--+--+----+--+----+
 \         /
  *----*---*
```

(Even better if I can modify x, but beggars can't be choosers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would approach it by making a new repo that will have the history you'd like using the [Convert Extention](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension):

1. Update the source repo to the the new "initial commit" (`x` in your diagram)
2. Copy (file copy, not clone!) to the target directory and `hg init` a new repo
3. use [`hg convert`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) with the `--splicemap` option to say "start at revision `x` in the source repo and apply it to revision 0 in the target repo". e.g. (note: untested!)
   `hg convert --splicemap splicemap.txt .\old-repo .\new-repo`
   and `splicemap.txt` has
   `[hash-of-x-in-old-repo] [hash-of-x-in-new-repo]`
4. I'd then zip up the source repo in case I ever needed it again :)

Comment: could you explain how should the options be selected? I'm unable to do such.

Comment: I added a basic example -- see [`hg convert`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) details for sure

Comment: thank you, I tried it but says "abort: splicemap entry 2aa2310e4e0a is not a valid revision identifier". I have set the splicemap with the hash of the origin and the target hash. "2aa2310e4e0a d1534db27c5a" just and space between the hashes , what might be wrong?

Comment: @diego.martinez - I'm guessing your issue is the following (quoted from the docs): "For Mercurial revisions you must use the full 40-digit hexadecimal hash to specify a revision"