# Create new mercurial repository cloning SINCE revision

Tags: mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a HUGE mercurial repository.

Cloning and some operations are starting to be slow. 
I would like to get rid of old commits, but keep the history of revisions since a specific date.

Is there any way to keep the commits SINCE a specific commit on a single branch, and collapse all the older parent commits in a single one?

R1 -> R2 ->R3 ->R4 ->R5 -> R6 -> R7 ->R8 ->Tip

[R1-5] ->R6 ->R7 ->R8 ->Tip

I tried to do such thing using GRAFT, but it did not work (maybe I don't now how to do it properly).

Optional: Is there such an option on Sourcetree?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compress away all parents in a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382143/compress-away-all-parents-in-a-repository)

Comment: The splicemap option mentioned in the other question should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot clone it to achieve this. But you have basically two options:

1. history rewrite using [histedit](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HisteditExtension) (it's an default extension, but needs enabling)
   It gives you the option to fold commits, that is combine several one to a single.
2. [convert](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) (which in essence is also a history rewrite)
   This gives you the chance to create a new repository with only the selected commits and branches. Thus you can simply leave out the first 4 commits and start with the 5th.

For each also checkout the help shipped with mercurial (`hg help histedit`, `hg help convert`).

Comment: ok , ,lets see if I get it. If I hg clone -b mybranch , I would have a repo with all the history but only my branch. Then, if I say I want from rev 5 to tip, how should I set the histedit opts?

Comment: you pick the commits you want to edit. And then you fold them. The linked wiki page has an example of that and especially the readme linked https://bitbucket.org/durin42/histedit/src/tip/README?fileviewer=file-view-default - it is not a single command